# PHP Variable Not Working in SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

I am a total beginner when it comes to PHP and SQL so please forgive me. Trying to figure out why my SQL statement will not work when passing it a variable for tblEmployees.Workgroup. It works perfectly fine when I put "CS Lead" vs the variable. Please let me know if I need to include any other information. Thanks!

```
<?php
include 'header.php'; //Include header
include 'sidebar.php'; //Include sidebar

$workgroup = 'CS Lead';

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT 
                    tblSchedule.CurrentSchedule, 
                    tblSchedule.Login,
                    tblSchedule.StartTime,
                    tblSchedule.EndTime,
                    tblSchedule.Sunday,
                    tblSchedule.Monday,
                    tblSchedule.Tuesday,
                    tblSchedule.Wednesday,
                    tblSchedule.Thursday,
                    tblSchedule.Friday,
                    tblSchedule.Saturday,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk1_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk1_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk2_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk2_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk3_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk3_End,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch2_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch2_End,
                    tblSchedule.TM_Day,
                    tblSchedule.TM_Start,
                    tblSchedule.TM_End,
                    tblEmployees.Workgroup
                FROM tblSchedule
                LEFT JOIN tblEmployees
                ON tblSchedule.Login=tblEmployees.Login
                WHERE CurrentSchedule='Y' AND tblEmployees.Workgroup = ' . $workgroup . '
                LIMIT 100");

$stmt -> execute();
?>
```

Comment: You need single quotes around string constants.  However, you should really be using parameters to pass in such values.

Comment: Updated based on what I think you mean. Still not working.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes...

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT 
                    tblSchedule.CurrentSchedule, 
                    tblSchedule.Login,
                    tblSchedule.StartTime,
                    tblSchedule.EndTime,
                    tblSchedule.Sunday,
                    tblSchedule.Monday,
                    tblSchedule.Tuesday,
                    tblSchedule.Wednesday,
                    tblSchedule.Thursday,
                    tblSchedule.Friday,
                    tblSchedule.Saturday,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk1_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk1_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk2_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk2_End,
                    tblSchedule.Brk3_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Brk3_End,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch2_Start,
                    tblSchedule.Lunch2_End,
                    tblSchedule.TM_Day,
                    tblSchedule.TM_Start,
                    tblSchedule.TM_End,
                    tblEmployees.Workgroup
                FROM tblSchedule
                LEFT JOIN tblEmployees
                ON tblSchedule.Login=tblEmployees.Login
                WHERE CurrentSchedule='Y' AND tblEmployees.Workgroup = '$workgroup'
                LIMIT 100");
```

OR

```
WHERE CurrentSchedule='Y' AND tblEmployees.Workgroup = {$workgroup}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!